# Quote from Helix episode Oubliette

Tags: story-identification, quotes, helix

In season 2 episode 5 of Helix one of the characters says "We're so far past panic, it would take the light from panic a hundred years to reach us." I know this a reference to something I just can't remember what. I seem to remember someone in a book or movie saying something like "we're so far apart it would take light a thousand years to travel between us" in reference to a disagreement. Does anybody know what I could be thinking of?

Comment: I'm unsure if this is a reference to another sci-fi series but I see [multiple instances](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22it+would+take+the+light+from%22+AND+%22so+far+*%22&start=10) of this wording being used as far back as 2004;

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pgp33-EVqXk

Comment: Thanks, so the phrasing is more common than I had imagined and therefor its probably not a reference to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just came to me. It was an episode of the tv show Hannibal I was thinking of. Specifically season 2 episode 1 "Kaiseki" in which Will Graham says to Hannibal

> You're not my friend. The, light from friendship won't reach us for a
>   million years. That's how far away from friendship we are.

I think the phrasing resonated with me because I'm such a fan of space-based scifi. But now I don't think its a reference just a common metaphor like Richard said.